# Issue with colorbar in pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a two dimensional numpy matrix (say, `Kappa`) using `pcolor` .

The skeleton of the code is this:

```
from pylab import pcolor, show, colorbar, xticks, yticks
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
pcolor(np.transpose(Kappa))
plt.colorbar()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

At the top of the colorbar, I see a weird way in which the highest scale of the colorbar is written. I have attached a picture of the the said output (and I have highlighted the troublesome part by putting it inside a red box.) [image]

Following suggestions, I have uploaded the matrix to my Google Drive. You can use this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yIhdoe8-J-0zsPY8ayyns4t7AmsAfjLL/view?usp=sharing) to access the matrix.

I am wondering if anyone has faced similar issues with colorbars in pylab? I will appreciate any help.

Comment: How should it be shown according to your opinion?

Comment: @eyllanesc : I am hoping to see a single number. More specifically, I am expecting a negative number (~1.357) times 10^(-7).  The minimum element of the matrix is -1.35783 * 10^(-7), the maximum element is -1.35751 * 10^(-7) and the mean is -1.35774*10^(-7). Also, I am not very sure why I am seeing the deep blue/violet patch at the edges. The matrix that I have plotted is of shape: 128*128.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc: I appreciate your feedback. But, I am wondering if there is a way in which I can give more information here (the matrix is huge, 128*128). I was hoping to see if any other person may have encountered similar things.

Comment: save the data in a .txt, upload it to somewhere like drive, dropbox, etc and share the link.

Comment: @ellanesc: I have uploaded the matrix to a drive, and I have put a shareable link in the original post now.

Comment: You still need to tell how you want it to look like instead. What number do you want to show on top and what numbers do you want to show on the scale?

Comment: The format at the top of the bar means, for example, that the bottom value of the bar is -1.357e-7 - 8.0e-11.  If you don't mind scaling you could plot with `pcolor(1e7*np.transpose(Kappa))` for a cleaner scale.